Unable to build x64dbg plugin
I'm trying to build an x64dbg plugin in visual Studio, but I keep getting the errors:

'getField': identifier not found** and **unnamed class used in
typedef name cannot declare members other than non-static data
members, member enumerations, or member classes

These errors are from the plugin SDK in the file called _dbgfunctions.h.
I'm using the x64dbg plugin template.
https://github.com/x64dbg/PluginTemplate
How can I fix this?
